Passing parameters to the Delta Live table through a config file stored in dbfs
I am reading data from ADLS location. I have connection details. I need to pass these parameters through a config file. There are several parameters for different layers(bronze and silver) DLT pipeline. I tried the following -
bronze_json_path = "/filestore/bronze_schema.json"
json_path = spark.conf.get("bronze.data_path", bronze_json_path)

This didn't work as expected. Is there any other tried way to parameterize the DLT?

Where have you specified your connection credentials? Can you paste your complete DLT code? When you say it's not working is there an error?
